# more rmonad libraries?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I want to do some rudimentary things with `RMonad`. Are there ways of using the "as monad" functionality to

- have an identity rmonad, to apply monad transformers to?
- have common things like `StateT` transformers?
- add a constraint to an existing monad? (e.g. if one wanted a `StateT` with additional constraints)

unfortunately I haven't yet grasped things like data families, etc. that make it work ... otherwise I'd probably be happy to write the code myself.

### edit

I hacked `StateT` together from library sources, will see if it works ...

[ http://pastebin.com/VT3uyEgr ]

Comment: You don't need to use CPP to make a context synonym.  You can use a class declaration with a single instance declaration instead.

Comment: right, I knew that, thanks! I'm using it for more now though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your version of StateT looks correct after a quick glance.  Unfortunately, using RMonad et. al. *does* require duplicating just about everything; I started doing writing some code using Suitable and gave up because it involved too much duplication (and in the end I didn't really need it).

**Edit:**

From my memory of how `Suitable` works, it's something like this:

Consider the `Functor` class: `Set` can't be an instance of it because it needs the extra `Ord` constraint.

A naive approach would be something like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

import qualified Data.Set as S

class MyFunctor c a | c -> a where
      myfmap :: (MyFunctor c b) => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b

instance (Ord a) => MyFunctor S.Set a where
      myfmap = S.map
```

But this then returns the following error:

```
Error: test.hs:11:16: Could not deduce (Ord b) arising from a use of `S.map'
    from the context (Ord a)
      bound by the instance declaration at /tmp/test.hs:10:10-37
    or from (MyFunctor S.Set b)
      bound by the type signature for
                 myfmap :: MyFunctor S.Set b => (a -> b) -> S.Set a -> S.Set b
      at /tmp/test.hs:11:7-20
    Possible fix:
      add (Ord b) to the context of
        the type signature for
          myfmap :: MyFunctor S.Set b => (a -> b) -> S.Set a -> S.Set b
        or the instance declaration
    In the expression: S.map
    In an equation for `myfmap': myfmap = S.map
    In the instance declaration for `MyFunctor S.Set a'
```

Why is this?  It's because the constraint isn't kept or found at the instance level, so GHC doesn't realise that when using `myfmap`, there should be an `Ord` constraint on `b`.

The `Suitable` type is used to explicitly create a constraint dictionary which allows you to specify these kinds of constraints:

```
import Data.Suitable
import qualified Data.Set as S

class MyFunctor c where
      myfmap :: (Suitable c a, Suitable c b) => (a -> b) -> c a -> c b

instance MyFunctor S.Set where
      myfmap f s = withConstraintsOf s
                   $ \ SetConstraints
                       -> withResConstraints $ \ SetConstraints -> S.map f s
```

(where `SetConstraints` is already defined in `Data.Suitable`)

This implementation works, but it does make type signatures a bit more convoluted, and method implementations a bit hairier (note here that we need to bring in `SetConstraints` *twice*: once for the `Set a`, the other for the `Set b`).  Note that for types without any constraints, none of the `Suitable` constraint functions are needed.

I had started to try and create `Suitable` versions of the classes in the Typeclassopedia but gave up because the instances were getting rather hairy.

Comment: If you have some intuition for how the `Context` mechanism works, a quick 2-sentence summary would help a lot, thanks!

Comment: @gatoatigrado: though [this blog post](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127) shows that soon might have nicer ways of writing RMonad-like classes!